# Facebook integration for a PhoneGap app

Tags: facebook, cordova

I have a working PhoneGap (2.9) app and want to add Facebook integration using the PhoneGap/Facebook plugin. On the Facebook app registration page, I am having trouble working out how to supply the required information. I gather I need to list 'Native iOS' and 'Native Android' apps as methods, but with the Android choice in particular, where does 'Class Name' come from? The Facebook web site says it's the 'Class name of the main activity you want Facebook to launch' but to me this makes no sense in the PhoneGap environment.

Comment: Did you ever work it out? I'd like to know what to put for the Android class as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it just means the main class of the app, as that's the only activity in the Android app

So if your app is called "MyApp", your package name is `com.example.myapp` then the "Class Name" field would be:

```
com.example.myapp.MyApp
```

[image: Completed Android platform section of Facebook App settings]

So if it wasn't a phonegap app, you could have Facebook launch a different activity if some one clicks on an FB notification.

Answer (score 0):

@William I had this issue too here is what worked after some help

1.The facebook app namespace has to go into the config.xml under the facebook connect plugin "app name".

2.The facebook the package name is the package id of your app from the config Not the facebook app display name.

3. The Facebook classname will be HelloCordova, this is the default class called with Phonegap

I am using 0.9.0 version of the Phonegap plugin

I think they will update the read me doc in the near future.

Hope this will help